# Subsetting string column in datatable using positions from another column

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

I have a data table which contains multiple columns of the following type:

```
   attr1 attr2
1: 01001 01000
2: 11000 10000
3: 00100 00100
4: 01100 01000

DT = setDT(structure(list(attr1 = c("01001", "11000", "00100", "01100"), 
    attr2 = c("01000", "10000", "00100", "01000")), .Names = c("attr1", 
"attr2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))
```

All of the columns are strings not numbers.
What I would like to achieve is the following:

1) I want to find the positions that the "1" appears in the strings of attr1

2) Take the values of attr2 in these positions

My result in this case would be:

```
[1] "10" "10" "1"  "10"
```

As an example in the first row, attr1 has "1" in positions 2 and 5, I subset the first row of attr2 in positions 2 and 5 and end up with "10".

What I have thought to do is to strsplit the columns and then work with that but I really hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use base R's `regmatches` to supply a different string for matching and replacement:

```
dt[, matches := sapply(regmatches(attr2, gregexpr('1+', attr1)), paste, collapse = '')][]
#>    attr1 attr2 matches
#> 1: 01001 01000      10
#> 2: 11000 10000      10
#> 3: 00100 00100       1
#> 4: 01100 01000      10
```

---

Data

```
dt <- structure(list(attr1 = c("01001", "11000", "00100", "01100"), 
        attr2 = c("01000", "10000", "00100", "01000")), .Names = c("attr1", 
    "attr2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

setDT(dt)
```

Comment: I didn't expect it, but your regmatches + sapply + paste is substantially quicker than doing the regmatches replacement.

Comment: @thelatemail Curious, I wouldn't expect that either. There are some time penalties hidden in some of the base regex functions, though. `stringi::stri_c_list` may be faster yet, as it's purpose-built, but I can't figure out how to do the whole thing in stringi without `Map`ing `stri_sub` across `stri_locate` results.

Comment: Well, I should note that it was 1M cases, with the difference being 12secs vs 20 secs. It's unlikely to break the bank, but I can't think of a faster alternative with comparable code complexity than what you have already.

Comment: `dt[, mapply(function(x,y) paste(y[x==1],collapse=""), strsplit(attr1,""), strsplit(attr2,""))]` seems quicker again, but it's ugly!

Comment: @thelatemail Hm, that takes longer on my machine. stringi (`dt[, matches := stri_c_list(Map(stri_sub, attr2, stri_locate_all_regex(attr1, '1+')))][]`) is a hint faster, but only about 0-10%.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a variation on @alistaire's `regmatches` answer, as there is also a replacement function `regmatches<-`. So, instead of extracting `1` values, replace `0` values with `""`:

```
dt[, matches := `regmatches<-`(attr2, gregexpr("0+", attr1), value="")]

#   attr1 attr2 matches
#1: 01001 01000      10
#2: 11000 10000      10
#3: 00100 00100       1
#4: 01100 01000      10
```

Your idea to `strsplit` and compare is also feasible:

```
dt[, matches := mapply(function(x,y) paste(y[x==1],collapse=""), strsplit(attr1,""), strsplit(attr2,""))]
```

Answer (score 3):

been working on this then saw @latemail comments

```
library(data.table)
DT = setDT(structure(list(attr1 = c("01001", "11000", "00100", "01100"),
    attr2 = c("01000", "10000", "00100", "01000")), .Names = c("attr1",
        "attr2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))

set.seed(0L)
N <- 1e5
dt <- data.table(attr1=do.call(paste0, data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, N*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))),
    attr2=do.call(paste0, data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, N*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))))

func_woSapply <- function() {
    dt1 <- copy(dt)
    dt1[, matches := `regmatches<-`(attr2, gregexpr("0+", attr1), value="")]
    dt1
}

func_withSapply <- function() {
    dt2 <- copy(dt)
    dt2[, matches := sapply(regmatches(attr2, gregexpr('1+', attr1)), paste, collapse = '')]
    dt2
}

func_useLogical <- function() {
    dt3 <- copy(dt)
    dt3[, matches := {
            d <- lapply(.SD, strsplit, "")
            lapply(mapply(function(x, y) y[as.logical(as.numeric(x))],
                d[["attr1"]], d[["attr2"]], SIMPLIFY=TRUE), paste, collapse="")
        }]
    dt3
}

library(stringi)
func_stringi <- function() {
    dt4 <- copy(dt)
    dt4[, matches := stri_c_list(Map(stri_sub, attr2, stri_locate_all_regex(attr1, '1+')))]
    dt4
}

func_indexing <- function() {
    dt[, mapply(function(x,y) paste(y[x==1],collapse=""), strsplit(attr1,""), strsplit(attr2,""))]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    func_woSapply=func_woSapply(),
    func_withSapply=func_withSapply(),
    func_useLogical=func_useLogical(),
    func_stringi=func_stringi(),
    func_indexing=func_indexing(),
    times=10L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   func_woSapply 2167.8063 2167.8063 2167.8063 2167.8063 2167.8063 2167.8063     1
# func_withSapply 1693.5539 1693.5539 1693.5539 1693.5539 1693.5539 1693.5539     1
# func_useLogical 1317.5950 1317.5950 1317.5950 1317.5950 1317.5950 1317.5950     1
#    func_stringi  598.3469  598.3469  598.3469  598.3469  598.3469  598.3469     1
#   func_indexing  816.8548  816.8548  816.8548  816.8548  816.8548  816.8548     1
```